# Find roots of $f(x)=\left(x^2-1\right)^2\left(x^2-2x+1\right)$

Tags: functions

I need to find the roots for the following function:

$$f(x)=\left(x^2-1\right)^2\left(x^2-2x+1\right)$$

I guess I already found one by doing this:

$$ f(x)=(x^2-1)^2(x^2-2x+1)\\
         (x^2-1)^2 = 0 | +1\\
          x^2 = 1      | √ \\
          x = 1 \\
          P₀₁(1|0)$$

But I could need some help, to find the second zero digit.

Comment: Do you mean zero, as in root? By inspection $\pm 1$, with $1$ occurring to multiplicity $3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, surely you meant multiplicity $4$.  (As the exasperated pianist said to Einstein, can't you count?)

Comment: Count I can do OK, much of the time. *See* is a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $f(x) = 0$.

$$(x-1)^2(x+1)^2(x-1)^2=(x-1)^4(x+1)^2= 0 $$

Then roots are $x_1=1$ multiplicity $4$ and $x_2=-1$ multiplicity $2$.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to The Case of the Missing Root:

In general,  we have $$x^2 = a^2 \iff x= \pm\sqrt {a^2} \iff x = \pm a$$

In this case, then $$x^2= 1 \iff x = \pm \sqrt 1 \iff x=\pm 1$$

So yes, $x = 1$ is one solution to $x^2 = 1$, and the other is $x=-1$. It never hurts to go back to check out your solutions by "plugging them into" the original equation for verification.

Tip: One way to remember to include *both* positive and negative roots of a quadratic such as this is to recognize when you have a *difference of squares*:

$$\begin{align} 
x^2 = a^2 &\iff x^2 - a^2 = 0\tag{difference of squares}\\ \\ 
& \iff (x+a)(x-a) = 0 \\ \\ 
&\iff x=-a\;\;\text{or}\;x =a
\end{align}$$

---

Now, putting it all together, we have 
$$\begin{align} f(x)& =\left(x^2-1\right)^2\left(x^2-2x+1\right)\\\\
& = \Big((x+1)(x-1)\Big)^2\left(x-1\right)^2\\\\
&= (x+1)^2(x-1)^4\\\\
f(x) &= (x+1)^2(x-1)^4 = 0 \implies x= -1\, \text{ or }\, x = 1.
\end{align}$$

The multiplicity of each root can be found by looking at the exponents: Root $x=1$ has *multiplicity* four, and root $x = -1$ has multiplicity two.

Answer (score -1):

A good way to find zeroes of a function is to see if you can write it as a multiplication of pieces, $f(x) = (x-\alpha)\cdot (x-\beta)\cdot(x-\gamma)\dots\cdot(x-\omega)$  If you can, then $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\cdots$ are all roots of the equation.

For your function:

$f(x)=(x^2-1)^2\cdot(x^2-2x+1)$

$f(x) = ((x+1)(x-1))^2\cdot (x-1)\cdot(x-1)$

$f(x) = (x+1)(x+1)(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)$

Going from the first line to the second, note that $x^2 - 1$ is the difference of squares and for $x^2-2x+1$ it is the square of $x-1$

Thus the two roots are $+1$ with multiplicity 4 and $-1$ with multiplicity 2